# how do i convert to assembly code (AVR assembly) from arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, temperature-sensor, assembly

i have code in the Arduino ide for a temperature sensor that shows the temperature on three 7 segment displays, it shows the temperature to one decimal point. using an arduino uno. I am struggling to convert the below code to assembly. can someone please help?

```
#include <SevSeg.h>
#include "SevSeg.h" // Included the library for the 7 segment display
SevSeg sevseg;  // Created an object
const int sensor_pin = A0; // initialized A0 for LM35 sensor
float tempc;  //variable to store temperature in degree Celsius
float sensor_out;  // variable to store the output
unsigned long interval = 1000; // the time we need to wait
unsigned long previousMillis = 0; // millis() returns an unsigned long.
void setup() {
 pinMode(sensor_pin, INPUT);  // Declared the sensor pin as Input
 byte numDigits = 3;      it to 3.
 byte digitPins[] = {10, 11, 12};   
 segment displays
 byte segmentPins[] = {9, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4};   
 pins of displays
 bool resistorsOnSegments = true;
 bool updateWithDelaysIn = true;
 byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_CATHODE;   // Type of display we are using
 sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments);
 sevseg.setBrightness(100);  
 }
 void loop() {
  sensor_out = analogRead(sensor_pin); 
  tempc = (sensor_out * 500) / 1024; 
  tempc = tempc - 32;
 tempc = tempc * 5;
 tempc = tempc / 9;
 delay_function(); 
 sevseg.refreshDisplay(); 
}
void delay_function() {
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval) {
sevseg.setNumber(tempc, 1);   // Sets temperature on display
previousMillis = millis();
}
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to just let the compiler do it for you.

Comment: Why would you want to? What are you going to do with the assembly code?

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=50169.0

Comment: According to a comment in the code, you are using an LM35, which is calibrated in Celsius (10 mV/°C). Yet the code does what looks like a Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion, which would make sense with an LM34, but not with an LM35.

Comment: with the assembly code i am going to use it in atmel studio to upload it onto an arduino and run the program. i also want to see what it looks like and i am also learning assembly code.

Comment: @dirshanramlall You can upload the `.hex` file using atmel studio as well!